# Memory usage keeps on increasing everytime I restart the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-memory

I created an app
The first activity which is launched is a fragment Activity.It has 4 fragments setup in a View pager....I have set  pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

## 2 of them has GridViews in it,where images are being loaded by Lazy List

(images are stored in the device..also the scroll is a bit laggy,any idea why?,also when all the images are loaded it takes up alot of more memory...don't know why that may be happening ,i thought lazylist library manages the memory itself...)

## I am using parallax background and I am setting up random background everytime the activity restarts...

## I am using custom fonts....

I am totally confused on why this could be happening.I am new to Android and i don't know what i should be looking into..I thought garbage collector would do it's job automatically. Any guidance will surely help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because that ur image is too big that it takes a lot of memory. try to use the example that android has given to scale down the memory usage of bitmap.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I am scaling them down,infact the lazylist library does it for me.....
by the way that doesn't explain why Memory usage keeps on increasing everytime I restart the app